# `FeatureContext` context class not found and can not be used.

Tags: symfony, testing, behat

I'm new with symfony2 and i wnat to test my app using behat but when I followed the official install in this link http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/cookbooks/1.symfony2_integration.html#installing-and-enabling-symfony2-extension
i got this error :
[Behat\Behat\Context\Exception\ContextNotFoundException]
  `FeatureContext` context class not found and can not be used.
it was just after the  first line and when i ran the bin/behat command.

Answer (score 0):

When using the Symfony2Extension, you are responsible for handling the autoloading. Make sure the `FeatureContext` class can be autoloaded by changing your `composer.json` autoload configuration and running `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: thanks WouterJ , after  clearing the cache , the problem was resolved